# CSS-JAVASCRIPT Object.style.display = value NOT working (Rotate device)

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, rotation

**HTML**

body:

```
<div id="site_content">
    <p id="orientation">Rotate device to determine orientation</p>
    <div class="rotateDevice" id="img_landscape">
       <img src="img/tablet_landscape.png" alt="Rotate your device!" />
    </div> 
    <div class="rotateDevice" id="im_portrait">
       <img src="img/tablet_portrait.png" alt="Rotate your device!" />
    </div> 
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** (script.js)

```
var lastOrientation;
function readDeviceOrientation() {

    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
        // Landscape
        document.getElementById("orientation").innerHTML = "LANDSCAPE";
        document.getElementById("im_portrait").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("im_landscape").style.display='block';
    } else {
        // Portrait
        document.getElementById("orientation").innerHTML = "PORTRAIT";
        document.getElementById("im_portrait").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("im_landscape").style.display='none';
    }

    if (lastOrientation !== window.orientation) {
        lastOrientation = window.orientation;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

window.onorientationchange = readDeviceOrientation;

window.onload = function () {
    readDeviceOrientation();
};

readDeviceOrientation();
timer = setInterval(readDeviceOrientation, 1/60);
```

I'd like alternate **#im_landscape** and **#im_portrait** images, but via javascript just works the *innerHTML*, but not *style.display*

How can i fix it, please?

Thank you everybody

Comment: #im_landscape does not exist. you have #img_landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
document.getElementById("im_landscape").style.display='block';
```

should be

```
 document.getElementById("img_landscape").style.display='block';
```

since your id is `id="img_landscape"`

and since jquery is tagged,you can use hide(),show() and id selector... looks clean and easy to read.

this

```
document.getElementById("orientation").innerHTML = "LANDSCAPE";
document.getElementById("im_portrait").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("im_landscape").style.display='block';
```

ends up like..

```
$("#orientation").html("LANDSCAPE");
$("#im_portrait").hide();
$("#img_landscape").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

check your land scape DIV ID in your JS,seems mis spelled
img_landscape is given as im_landscape..